# Solving A*x=x with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, math, matrix, calculation

I am new to numpy and I want to solve the equation `A * x = x`, where A is a matrix and x is a vector.

Searching for the vector x, if it exists.

I found the `np.linalg.solve()`-function , but didn't got it to work as intended.

Comment: You might want to check this out because NumPy has a few different methods depending on what kind of multiplication you want to do: https://www.educba.com/matrix-multiplication-in-numpy/. It's hard to say more without knowing more specifics of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Is `A` known to you? If so why don't you just compute the eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Comment: Show what you tried. "I didn't get it to work as intended" is not a valid problem statement.

Comment: Please accept the provided answer by clicking on the check mark next to it to remove your question from the unanswered queue

Answer (score 4):

The issue here is not so much a problem with numpy as with your understanding of the linear algebra involved. The question you are asking can be rephrased as:

```
A @ x = x
A @ x = I @ x
(A - I) @ x = 0
```

This is a specific formulation of the the general [eigenvector](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Eigenvector.html) problem, with the stipulation that the [eigenvalue](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Eigenvalue.html) is 1.

Numpy solves this problem with the function [`np.linalg.eig`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html):

```
w, v = np.linalg.eig(A)
```

You need to check if any of the values are 1 (there could be more than one):

```
mask = np.isclose(w, 1)
if mask.any():
    for vec in v[:, mask].T:
        print(vec)
else:
    print('Nope!')
```

The elements of `v` are unit vectors. Keep in mind that any scalar multiple of such a vector is also a solution.

For issues with non-invertible matrices, you may want to use [`scipy.linalg.svd`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.svd.html) instead:

```
v, w, _ = svd(A)
```

The rest of the procedure will be the same.